# How can I clear another tty from C?

Tags: terminal, c

In a terminal I can clear another terminal by running:

```
echo -e "\033\0143" > /dev/pts/14
```

However, if I try this from my C program by doing:

```
system("echo -e '\033\0143' > /dev/pts/14");
```

it doesn't clear the screen and leaves some garbage. Any ideas on how to do this?

I have been programming in C for 30 years and thought this would be easy.

Answer (score 5):

The `\0143` escape is being interpreted by C, not by the shell or `echo`, and it's treated as having `\014` and then the numeral `3`. This ends up writing the bytes `1b 0c 33 0a` to the tty, rather than `1b 63 0a`. `-e` isn't doing anything at all at this point.

I don't understand why you would do this rather than opening the tty file and writing the bytes directly with `write(3)`, though. In any case, this is really a programming question.

Comment: Dang it, I should have thought of that. Thank you very much I have it working properly now. I stuck the proper sequence directly into a string and "systemed" that. Crude but works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You must escape backslash `\`, otherwise, C will treat your sequence as [special characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

```
system("echo -e '\\033\\0143' > /dev/pts/14");
```